# Storyboard - UITabBarController

Tags: ios, ios5

I was playing around with iOS 5 and storyboards today. I currently have it so that the main storyboards starts with a uitabbarcontroller then a navigationviewcontroler and finally a uiviewcontroller. All that works fine.

What I'm looking for is how to dynamically set which viewconotroller the uitabbarcontroller is displaying when the application starts. So I'd want to use CoreData to see if a table was empty and it it was select the second viewcontroller (tabbar item 2) and if not select the first viewcontroller (tabbar item 1).

Since the storyboard is handling what is being displayed, I wasn't sure how in the app delegate I could set this?

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here!

Thanks!

Comment: good question dude. Here's a vote so you can vote as well

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your app delegate will have a window property. That can be used to get a pointer to the storyboard's initial view controller (which will be your UITabBarController), like this example from one of my app delegates application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UITabBarController *tabController =
   (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.selectedIndex =
   [defaults integerForKey:kOptionLastTabSelectedKey];
tabController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I've used it. But what about getting any other view controller in the storyboard? is there a way to do that?

Comment: There is the – instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method of UIStoryboard (assuming you have set the identifier string for the view controllers you want to access), although this will *create* a new view controller instance. The ones that are created from storyboard segues in your app are available, of course, in the prepareForSegue: method of the source view controller.

Comment: you can get the selected ViewController with something like this: (UINavigationController *)[tabController selectedViewController]. all other ViewControllers are stored in the property viewControllers. It's an array of ViewControllers managed by the TabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

For me I can access the tabbar using self.navigationController.parentViewController;
This always return the tabbar controller.